# a proof that $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is generated by compact subsets of $\mathscr{R}$

Tags: measure-theory

Is my argument correct?

Let $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ be the Borel subsets of $\mathbb{R}$,and let $\mathscr{A}$ be the $\sigma-algebra$ generated by the collection of all compact subsets of $\mathbb{R}$. It is know that $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})$ is generated by the collection of all closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, so that $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R}) \supset \mathscr{A}$. If $C$ is an unbounded closed subset of $\mathbb{R}$,then $C$ is equal to the union of the countable collection of all sets of the form $\bar{B_n}\cap C$ where $B_n$ is a ball of radius $n$. Each such set is closed and bounded so that it is compact. It follows that $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})\subset \mathscr{A}$. Hence $\mathscr{B}(\mathbb{R})=\mathscr{A}$.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is almost correct, but there is a small typo in it. I'm sure that you wanted to write that $C$ is the union of $C \cap \bar B_n$, where $B_n$ is a ball of radius $\pmb n$.

Comment: yes,Im really a scatterbrain